# How to add a timer in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am currently working with batch and made a prank thing (obligates you to close your pc) and an override section for me to get all my coding back so I wanted the person whit the wrong code to have my prank activate in 20 minutes I would like suggestions on how to do it?

```
:system
cls
set /p assurance=are you sure you want to do this (I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY DAMAGE DONE BY THIS COMMAND IF YOU ACCEPT TO MOVE ON.I WARN YOU THE ONLY WAY TO STOP THIS COMMAND IS RESTART YOUR PC.) 

echo -accept and move on
echo or
echo -stop this command
pause
if %assurance%==accept and move on goto initiate
if %assurance%==stop this command goto home
:wrong
cls
echo you have 20 minutes 
:initiate
cls
echo KILL CODE ACTIVATED ACTIVATED HAVE FUN!!!
:killer
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
start
goto killer


:override
cls
echo i need the override code to activate this command.
set /p code=code:

if %code%==42 is the answer to life but my answer is 2029 goto right
if not %code%==42 is the answer to life but my answer is 2029 goto wrong

:right
```

Comment: I don't think that the CPU will work 20 minutes with such a code.

Comment: oh ok then we;; i will add another code or somthing thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Use `timeout`.

```
timeout /t 1200 :: Waits twenty minutes.
```

By the way, you shouldn't write scripts like this. They're not funny, and can cause the current user of the computer you run them on to lose work or worse.

Comment: ty very much for the help